# Detecting threshold with an MCU at particular variation speed

Tags: microcontroller

In the drawing below, the black line illustrates a sensor output voltage as read by the ADC of a microcontroller.  The red line is a programmatically set threshold value and the green points where I need detection.

[image]

I will monitor the sensor output via the ADC of a microcontroller, but I want to trigger a relay only if the change in sensor output is fast. I want to detect when the sensor output goes below the threshold fast.

Inside a while loop I can monitor the sensor into a value called sensorReading, but the thing is I don't want to detect all points that goes below the threshold but only when the sensor output goes lower than threshold fast as illustrated in my drawing above.

What can be the approach/logic or method in such case?

**edit:** Normally the maximum to minimum increase and decease takes 3 minutes.  I would like for the microcontroller to detect when the decrease from the maximum to minimum (or to less than threshold) happens in anything less than 5 sec. I'm not into precision for this.

Comment: There's no timings in your question so it's impossible to say. Please can you edit your question and add this information. After that, you could maybe use a comparator, followed as needed by a monostable to lengthen the pulse, to drive a GPIO pin.

Comment: I made an edit hope make it more clear.

Comment: Maybe adding one more threshold and calculating the time elapsed between them to indicate the slope? But how to calculate the elapsed time. Im mostly looking for an approach.

Comment: Just take the derivative (slope) of the raw ADC data, possibly with suitable filtering to suppress noise in the data. If the value crosses the threshold AND the derivative has a large negative value, there's your trigger.

Comment: Doing this in the uC allows flexibility. But, given the large difference between fast and slow a simple analog solution would be easy.

Comment: @DaveTweed So I can take one ADC sample into an array every 100ms where the array size is 50. When the array is full I refill the array ect. Then I would have 50 points of last 5sec where the array is updated each 100ms. From that I can calculate the slope each 5 sec. Do you mean something like that?

Comment: @ATCSVOL Do you mean a Schmitt Trigger with a very large hysteresis?

Comment: @ty_1917 only sort of. Imagine a comparator with signal feeding one input and signal via an RC filter to the other plus a slight downwards bias to the RC driven input. If the signal falls far slower than the RC time constant then thecinput is always lower. But, if the signal falls faster than the RC time  constant the comparstor trips. Such an arrangement is sometimes used to demodulate a digital signal with no defined DC reference point. The signal provides its own average DC level via an RC filter  and the signal then varies  above and below this average point. It works ! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's some python code as an example. It generates a test signal, adds noise, then applies filtering to it. It's always a good idea to test your algo on the PC with something that can make plots before trying it on the micro.

I've used 120Hz sample rate. First I've applied a bit of FIR filtering to get rid of most of the noise and 50Hz ripple... that's the "In only want to spend 2-4 bytes of RAM on this thing" filter that everyone else uses:

```
out_sample = (1-x)*in_sample + x*out_sample
```

This mixes in a little bit of new sample into the current accumulator on very cycle, so it ends up converging to the sampled value, while ignoring quick variations and noise. Season to taste by changing the value of x according to the lowpass filter cutoff you want. On a micro you'd usually use the fixed point version, something like that:

```
out_sample = (in_sample*1 + out_sample*255) >> 8
```

And if you got a 12 bit DAC that will need 16bx16b to 32b MUL. But if you got a modern micro with a fast multiplier, who cares.

Basically if you have a tiny RAM micro and you want lowpass, use FIR, single or whatever higher order, biquads, etc.

However you require computing the slope of the signal (ie, derivative) and that adds back the noise that was removed. See second plot, the derivative of the filtered signal is quite noisy (blue, I forgot the legend). The solution is to compute the derivative over a much longer interval.

I've downsampled the signal by a factor of 50 via averaging, which corresponds to averaging 50 samples, storing that, averaging the next 50, and storing that.

Since you don't need fast reaction time, that uses less memory than a rolling average, which needs to store all the values. But it is a bit slower to react, so pick your favorite.

The derivative of this (difference between samples divided by intersample period) is in orange in the bottom graph, and it's a lot less noisy. Due to the filtering and averaging, it will also ignore short spikes. That may or may not be a benefit, depending if you want to ignore them or not.

Then simply compare the current value with the threshold, and the derivative with a suitable slope threshold, and you're set.

[image]

```
import os, pprint, time, datetime, psycopg2, traceback
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from path import Path


Fs = 300
Ts = 1/Fs
downsample = 50

# make signal

period = 60*3
freq = 1/period
length = int( Fs*period*1.5 )
t = (1.0/Fs) * np.arange( length )

# make signal
signal = np.sin( 2*np.pi*freq*t ) 
signal[int(Fs*period*1.25):] = -0.5

# add noise
adc = signal + 0.1*np.sin( 2*np.pi*50*t ) + np.random.normal( 0, 0.1, t.shape )

# filter signal usign simple IIR filter
# requires 16bx16b to 32b MUL on micro for fixpoint
# but uses very little RAM
filtered = np.zeros_like( adc )
filt_coef = 0.995
filt = 0
for i in range( length ):
    filtered[i] = filt = filt_coef*filt + (1-filt_coef)*adc[i]

# downsample after filtering
# this just sums the samples in buckets containing "downsample" samples
# you can use rolling average or anything else
downsampled = filtered.reshape( (length//downsample, downsample) ).mean(axis=1)
downsampled_t = t[::downsample]+downsample*Ts

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot( t, adc, label = "adc" )
plt.plot( t, signal, label = "signal" )
plt.plot( t, filtered, label = "filt" )
plt.plot( downsampled_t, downsampled, label = "adc" )
plt.legend()
plt.grid(1)

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot( t[1:], np.diff( filtered ) / Ts, label = "filtered diff" )
plt.plot( downsampled_t[1:], np.diff( downsampled ) / (Ts*downsample), label = "downsampled diff" )
plt.legend()
plt.grid(1)

plt.show()
```